# How to split a string into a list or array in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a long string like this:

```
"data source=qa2;initial catalog=rr;persist security info=True;user id=ka;password=lalala;Connection Timeout=60"
```

And I want to split it, let's say, to a string list. The list should be like:

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)
list(0) = qa2
List(1) = rr
List(2)= True
List(3) = ka
.......
```

How do I split it using VB.NET code?

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/split-vbnet

Comment: I need to split it on a way that I want to store what's after the "=" and move on to the second I mean: data source =qa2   so list(0) = qa2 ....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use String.Split to split the items at the ";" characters and then again to split each item at the "=" character.

```
Dim str As String = "data source=qa2;initial catalog=rr;persist security info=True;user id=ka;password=lalala;Connection Timeout=60"
Dim items() As String = str.Split(";"c)
Dim list As New List(Of String)
For i As Integer = 0 To items.Length - 1
    Dim elems() As String = items(i).Split("="c)
    If elems.Length > 1 Then list.Add(elems(1).Trim) Else list.Add("")
Next
```

Comment: How do I split it backwards means instead of getting qa2 I need the value that stands before the equal sign??? data source , catalog....

Comment: @HuyZukerman: To get the value that is before the equal sign instead of after, use `list.Add(elems(0).Trim)` instead of `list.Add(elems(1).Trim)`.

Comment: caution when using this technics to split CSV file lines ! Be sure that any value between " contains a ; !

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, `String.Split` is the obvious choice.  However, since the string appears to be a SQL Server connection string, you may also want to consider using the [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class to parse the connection string.  For instance:

```
Dim builder As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder("data source=qa2;initial catalog=rr;persist security info=True;user id=ka;password=lalala;Connection Timeout=60")
Console.WriteLine("Data Source: " & builder.DataSource)
Console.WriteLine("Initial Catalog: " & builder.InitialCatalog)
' ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `List(Of String)` and iterate:

```
Dim mylist As List(Of String) = yourstring.Split(",").ToList

For Each item As String In mylist
    ' Look at your items, split by comma into a list
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString)
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably overkill, but you could also do this with regular expressions, like so:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Linq

' ...

Dim str As String = "data source=qa2;initial catalog=rr;persist security info=True;user id=ka;password=lalala;Connection Timeout=60"

Dim values As String() = Regex.Match(str, "(.+?=(?<value>.+?)(;|$))+") _
    .Groups("value").Captures.Cast(Of Capture).Select(Function(c) (c.Value)).ToArray()
```